# "constexpr" in C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

So, as of C++14, the restrictions that `constexpr` had in C++11 are gone, such as having new variables or loops in the `constexpr` function.

And the latest versions of the GCC and Clang compilers already support them.

So the issue is this... A `constexpr` function is computed during compile time and not during execution, as long as the value being passed to it as a parameter is a constant. So the result of the function that I've written below should appear instantaneously during execution, right? But it doesn't.

My question is: why does that happen? And do I have a wrong understanding of C++14's `constexpr` feature? Thank you.

EDIT: Yes, I was using `-OO`, that is why it wouldn't work. But setting up `-O1` or higher speed optimization does the trick and the program executes as expected. Thank you all for your answers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

constexpr long long addition(long long num)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    std::cout << addition(500000000);  //500 mill //executes in 1.957 seconds

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    auto stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "\n\nIt took " << static_cast<double>(dur.count()) / 1000 << " seconds!";

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: A constexpr function *could be* computed during compile time, the compiler doesn't have to. Are you using `-O3` ?

Comment: gcc with `-O2` or higher replaces the call with a constant, [see here](http://goo.gl/O5jaIY)

Comment: also suggest `auto x = addition(500000000);` and leave the cout'ing to after the timing stops

Comment: Ahh, I'm stupid. Yes, it does get computed during compile time when I use -O3 optimization. Thanks a lot. For some reason I didn't think about that.

Comment: @sasauke Use a `constexpr auto a = addition(500000000)` to force evaluation at compilation time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> A constexpr function is computed during compile time and not during execution, as long as the value being passed to it as a parameter is a constant.

No, the compiler can do so at its discretion, just as with a "pure" function that isn't `constexpr`.  Unless you use it in a context where a compile-time constant is required, such as initialization of a constexpr variable, or use in an array bound (beware VLA g++ extension, though) or as a non-type template argument.  For these cases, compile-time evaluation is required.  (This is not an exhaustive list: there are other contexts which require compile time constants such as switch case labels, but how do you send a case label value to `cout`?)

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer of @Ben Voigt, here's an actual working example that runs in no time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

constexpr long long addition(long long num)
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    constexpr auto res = addition(500000);
    std::cout << res;  //500 mill //executes in 0 seconds

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    auto stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "\n\nIt took " << static_cast<double>(dur.count()) / 1000 << " seconds!";

    std::cin.get();
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1112484747ea2e94). Note that I had to shave off a few 0s from your input size. You can tweak this with using the `-fconstexpr-steps=N` compiler option (for Clang).